# Typesafe Stack 2.0.2 - Lifty Dependency

Tags: scala

Downloaded Typesafe Stack 2.0.2 and installed but typing sbt gives...

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.lifty#lifty;1.7.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Any clues?

Comment: Seems to be something to do with sbt 0.11.3.   Looks like lifty 1.7.4 isn't available for 0.11.3?

Comment: Deleted old .sbt and .lifty file (from very old previous versions of typesafe/play) from User home and retried....

Seems to resolve now.